# issues booting fresh install of UbuntuOS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, boot, grub

I have 2 hard drives on my server and i have previously installed CentOS on one of the hard drives(not sure which but i am guessing the second)

I install fresh Ubuntu 14.04LTS on the first one i will say but after the successful installation(which i assumes it has repartitioned my hard drives) when it reboots i get this error

`error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found`

I have attached screenshot below.

I tried to use rescue mode to fix what the issue is and am brought to a screen(see screenshot below as well) that asks to choose the boot device i want, and when i choose `/dev/sda1` it says ir can't use it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### 1. How do I fix this?

AND/OR

#### 2. How can I wipe out EVERYTHING on my 2 hard drives first, before starting another fresh install? (maybe easier for me to be honest)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to automatically fix problems with booting and GRUB.

I'm not quite sure how you installed it, but the boot loader needs to be installed to /dev/sda, and NOT /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda[any number]. The automatic installation should do this properly.

If you want to wipe everything and start over, you can use the GParted partition editor which can be found in the Ubuntu live session. Is your system UEFI-capable and 64-bit? Remove all partitions and then ensure that the drive is formatted as GPT for best compatibility with UEFI (you can create a new partition table under "Device" at the top).

Comment: exactly what i did using gparted before seeing your answer...answer came late but thanks..will accept anyways

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with how the 2 hard drives were configured inside boot menu, i made appropriate settings in boot menu so server understands i am using both hard drives separately and whola!